# Hide parent element if child element is visible

Tags: javascript, css

I'm not a JS dev, but I've been asked to do this at work being "the most technical guy" ‍♂️.

We use Google Tag Manager, and we can put tags in pause. I have been asked to hide the paused tags using JS, I'm just testing it out in the console now.

I have tried this

```
if ($('body > await-bootstrap-ng2 > ng-transclude > div > div > shrouter-view > gtm-tag-list-page > gtm-container-page > div > div > div.gtm-container-page-content-wrapper > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr > td.gtm-table__malware-column > i.pause-circle-filled-icon.no-padding').length)

$('body > await-bootstrap-ng2 > ng-transclude > div > div > shrouter-view > gtm-tag-list-page > gtm-container-page > div > div > div.gtm-container-page-content-wrapper > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr').hide();
```

Basically, when the yellow pause icon is visible on a tag, I want it to be hidden. But this code hides all the tags, even the active ones (Check image 1).

[image: Image 1]

I only want the specific tag (row) where the icon is displayed to be hidden. Is there a way for me to do this?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: _"But this code hides all the tags"_ - well of course it does, because you have not limited the selection of rows you actually hide, in any way. Just because you tested whether some specific DOM constellation exists, does not mean that test would now have any influence on your much broader selector you used the second time.

Comment: If the `$` is supposed to be jQuery - https://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: Hi @CBroe, Thanks for your comment ! How do I limit the selection only to the rows where the icon appears ?

Comment: Select your `tr` elements, then apply `has` to filter out only those that have a specific child you are looking for, and then apply `hide`.